# Hide pivot table items using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to check the Colum A and Column E value and then collapse the Pivot table based on the values.

```
myfile.Sheets(3).Select
Dim dd As Range
Dim ee As Range
Dim ff As String
     For Each ee In myfile.Sheets(3).Range("E1:E20000")
     For Each dd In myfile.Sheets(3).Range("A1:A20000")
         With ee
            If Left(dd.Value, 1) = "F" And ee.Value = "0.00" Or ee.Value = "(0.00)" Then ff = Left(dd.Value, 10)
            ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems(ff).ShowDetail = False
        End With
     Next
     Next
```

I think this where the error comes up. Specially with the variable ff.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems(ff).ShowDetail = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your string in Quotes. So like

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems(""" & ff & """).ShowDetail = False
```

Also if FF does not get set it still trys to collapse the pivot. So try putting that in an if statement so `if FF <> "" then .....showdetails = false`

EDIT updated code which should work.

```
myFile.Sheets(3).Select
Dim i As Long
Dim ff As String

For i = 5 To 5000
    If Left(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value, 1) = "F" And ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = "0" Then
        ff = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value, 10)
        If ff <> "" Then
            For j = 1 To ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems.Count
                If ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems(j).Name = ff Then
                    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems(j).ShowDetail = False
                End If
            Next
        End If

    End If
Next i
```

The pivotItems is looking for an Index. So I have looped through all of them to see if FF matches the name of them. If it does it will hide the details.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: I try this and still not working. I think there is another problem relates to selecting the range. I only want to compare the same row. Line A5 and E5 not each and every combination.

Comment: I update my coding with the one below, now there is no error, but nothing happens as well.

Comment: myfile.Sheets(3).Select
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ff As String
        For i = 5 To 5000
                         If Left(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value, 1) = "F" And ActiveSheet.Range("E" & i).Value = "0.00" _
             Then ff = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & i).Value, 10)
             If ff <> "" Then _
             ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Ref 1").PivotItems(ff).ShowDetail = False

             
                    Next i

Comment: I've updated the answer above. Let me know if it works.